# Ripple emulator failing to emulate

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I have been using Ripple via Visual Studio 2015 to debug my Ionic app but it has stopped working for me.

I get a message saying that it looks like the zombie apocalypse has started and two options - "Wait" or "Fire". The "Fire" is supposed to purge Ripple's settings. Neither works.

I created a new app using the Ionic tabs template, and it fails to emulate too, so I don't think the problem is in my app.
Any advice on how I can get Ripple working again?

**Edit**

I opened the Javascript console (Debug->Windows->JavaScript Console) and there is an  error message there:

> Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to set the 'ripple-last-load'
>   property on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'ripple-last-load'
>   exceeded the quota

Now, I was adding things to windows.localStorage, is it possible that the problem lies there? How do I clear it if I can't even get my app to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select More tools.
3. Select Clear browsing data.
4. Obliterate the following items from the past day. (I accepted the defaults but I expect that cached images and files is what got it working)

I still think that here is a problem in Ripple. It does not handle the error

> Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to set the 'ripple-last-load'
>   property on 'Storage'

I have raised it as an issue here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIPPLE-102