# How should I keep my Ionic / Apache Cordova / Visual Studio environment up to date?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am confused by the tools available for developing apps using Ionic / Apache Cordova / Visual Studio. I started by using the Ionic command line, then migrated to Visual Studio 2015 when I heard that they had introduced [tools for Apache Cordova](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/05/01/tools-for-apache-cordova-in-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx).  But now I hit [problem after](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32842702/150342) [problem with the Ripple emulator in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868731/emulator-crashing-out-when-i-attempt-to-open-developer-tools).

So I have tried to go back to the Ionic command line to emulate, but when I type `ionic emulate android` I get this error:

```
cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\..\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I also get a message that my local version of Ionic is out of date. I wonder if updating might fix the error, but I'm worried that if I update Ionic via the command line, that I break some dependency in the Visual Studio Tools For Apache Cordova.

I have read [where the Ionic framework fits in](http://blog.ionic.io/where-does-the-ionic-framework-fit-in/), and that 
[PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/), but I remain confused about how to keep things up to date and compatible.

My confusion is compounded by an announcement today that there are now [command line "Tools For Apache Cordova"](http://taco.tools/articles/announcingtaco.html) - "validated by our Visual Studio product team". Where does this fit with the [recently updated  "Tools for Apache Cordova"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/09/16/wintools-1-1-typescript-1-6-rtm-and-tools-for-apache-cordova-updates.aspx)  I already have in my Visual Studio Extensions and Updates?

So:

1. Can I safely update Ionic via the command line `ionic lib update` and still expect Visual Studio's tools to work?
2. What is causing the error when I try `ionic emulate android`?
3. Can anyone explain how these tools fit together, and how to keep them all up to date?

**EDIT - to add more info**
I think my confusion would be lessened if I understood how to use the latest version of Ionic and Cordova as if I hadn't started out using the Ionic command line and was only using Visual Studio.

The standard project template puts links in to `<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.5/js/ionic.bundle.min.js">` and `<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.5/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">` so can I assume that the bundle contains all the dependencies and that VS2015 downloads it when it is building the app and that all I have to do to do is change `1.0.0-rc.5` to `1.1.0`?

What about Cordova? My `taco.json` file specifies that it is version `4.3.0`. Do I simply change this when it is time to update Cordova and VS2015 will handle the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can safely update the Ionic command-line, it will not interfere with the VS tools.
2. Not sure about this, but updating might fix it (or even just unintalling/reinstalling Ionic).
3. The VS Cordova tools ship updates pretty frequently; you should update when you can. The updates should not affect Ionic, nor should updating Ionic affect the VS tools.

In general, the VS team has taken care to ensure that the needed npm packages are local, so that they will not be affected by changing/removing other packages (e.g. Ionic). Other prerequisites (NodeJS, Android SDK, etc.) are system-wide, but they won't be affected by an Ionic upgrade.

As for the blog post about the command-line tools: the TACO-CLI is a separate set of tools that are designed for developers who would prefer to use a CLI rather than VS. It is essentially a Cordova wrapper (similar to Ionic that way), where the basic Cordova functionality is augmented with new commands that simplify development in a number of ways. http://taco.tools has much more info.

TACO-CLI can be used alongside the VS tools if that makes your workflow easier. Neither will interfere with the other.

**Edit**: In response to your new questions:

1. Just updating the links in the standard Ionic template should be fine. Even if you don't update the CLI, the js/css that actually makes things go should be enough.
2. Yes, if you update the "cordova-cli" property in taco.json, the VS tools will automatically install and use the appropriate version locally. This will not affect the globally installed version (if it exists) so it will not affect other command-line tools that may depend on it. Note that you can change the version from the VS UI by opening the config.xml file, and editing it in the "Platforms" tab.

Source: I work on the VS Cordova Tools team.

Comment: One of the things that confused me was that I hadn't realised that the `ionic lib` tells me the version of the local javascript library in my `lib/ionic` folder (currently 1.1.0) and `ionic -v` tells me the version of the CLI (now 1.7.7 after I updated it using npm), and the two things are quite distinct.